# make command builds only the first target - Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to know if it is correct to say that, if i write the command `make` in the shell prompt, it will build only the first target in the makefile.

If i wanted to build another target, would i need to write:

`make target_name`?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: see: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/How-Make-Works.html

Comment: Hello @MadScientist can you do an example about building a target different from the one please?

Comment: You can run `make othertarget` to build the target `othertarget` regardless of where it appears in the makefile.

Comment: thank you so much @MadScientist so the answers to my questions are yes

Comment: Yes, as described in the documentation link I mentioned.  Also, you could just try it and see what happens...